# Is casting to const implied when casting to a narrower const location?

Tags: c++

I am trying to word this as best as possible, but an example is a good way to demonstrate my question. Consider the following scenario where variable `long a` goes into a narrower array element - essentially `const int b[0]`:

```
long a = 584;
const int b[4] = {(const int) a, 0, 0, 0};
```

Is the following snippet equivalent considering that the const isn't explicitly defined:

```
long a = 584;
const int b[4] = {(int) a, 0, 0, 0};
```

Both compile, but does the standard define this scenario and outcomes?

Comment: It doesn't matter here, since the value is always copied anyway.

Comment: That's a good point, thank you. I'm guessing that the output assembly is identical in that case as casting is - in a simplistic sense - a compiler hint.

Comment: What's the point of the array? Do you think there's a difference between these and `const int b = (const int) a;` / `const int b = (int) a;`?

Comment: @molbdnilo No point, just a random example copy pasted from some test code like I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting to `const int` produces a value of type `int`. There are no cv-qualified prvalues of non-class type. See [expr.cast]/1:

> The result of the expression `(T)` *cast-expression* is of type `T`. The result is an lvalue if `T` is an lvalue reference
>   type or an rvalue reference to function type and an xvalue if `T` is an rvalue reference to object type; otherwise
>   the result is a prvalue. [ *Note:* if `T` is a non-class type that is cv-qualified, **the cv-qualifiers are ignored when
>   determining the type of the resulting prvalue**; see 3.10. — *end note* ]

and [basic.lval]/4:

> Class prvalues can have cv-qualified types; **non-class prvalues always have cv-unqualified types**. Unless
>   otherwise indicated (5.2.2), prvalues shall always have complete types or the void type; in addition to these
>   types, glvalues can also have incomplete types.

So even though you write a cast to `const int`, the resulting value will have type `int`.

However, a language lawyer might ask whether the `(int)` cast and the `(const int)` cast are guaranteed to produce *the same value.* Obviously in your case `584` fits into `int` so the value is guaranteed to be `584`. In the general case where the `long` value might not fit into an `int`, the last bullet point of [dcl.init]/16 guarantees that the result of casting to `const int` will still be the same as casting to `int`:

> ... Otherwise, the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the ini-
>   tializer expression. Standard conversions (Clause 4) will be used, if necessary, to convert the initializer
>   expression to the **cv-unqualified version of the destination type**;

(All wording is from the C++14 standard; emphasis is mine.)

Answer (score 2):

No, `const` is not implicitly added by the compiler, because it doesn't change anything. Both of your snippets are equivalent.

I don't think the standard defines this scenario, because it's a bit contrived.

Your question is equivalent whether it matters whether `a` is `const` here or not (in the example bellow). The answer is no, it doesn't, because you are copying `a`. It doesn't matter that you can't write to `a`, because you are only doing a read, not a write.

```
/*const*/ int a = 10;
const int b = a;
```

Comment: By definition, unless the example has undefined behavior, it is defined by the standard.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Or the standard says that it's up to the implementation. What I mean is that that specific example isn't in a code example in the standard.